# How to update the contact lists of an email address in the Send grid?

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm utilizing the SendGrid API to manage contacts and their associated contact lists. Referring to the documentation [here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact), I initially created an email address and assigned it to Contact Lists (XXXXX, YYYYY) using the following request:

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer <<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>>" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"list_ids":["057204d4-755b-4364-a0d1-XXXXXX", "057204d4-755b-4364-a0d1-YYYYY"], "contacts": [{"email": "annahamilton@example.org"}]}'
```

Now, I want to update the contact's associated Contact List to another one (ZZZZZ) using the same request. So, I issued the following command:

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer <<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>>" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"list_ids":["057204d4-755b-4364-a0d1-ZZZZZ"], "contacts": [{"email": "annahamilton@example.org"}]}'
```

However, upon searching for the email address using the following request:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts/search/emails" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer <<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>>" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"emails": ["annahamilton@example.org"]}'
```

I noticed that the email address's contact list was not updated to ZZZZ; instead, all three lists are still present:

```
{
    "result": {
        "annahamilton@example.org": {
            "contact": {
                ...........
                "email": "annahamilton@example.org",
                "list_ids": [
                    "057204d4-755b-4364-a0d1-XXXXXX",
                    "057204d4-755b-4364-a0d1-YYYYYY",
                    "057204d4-755b-4364-a0d1-ZZZZZZ"
                ],
               ..........
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please guide me on how to properly update the Contact Lists associated with an email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I noticed that the email address's contact list was not updated to ZZZZ; instead, all three lists are still present

That was to be expected - https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact#body says,

> `list_ids`- array[string] - An array of List ID strings that this contact will be added to.

Doesn't say there that the contact will get removed from other lists they are already on.

To remove a contact from a list, you need to go *via* the lists endpoint, `/v3/marketing/lists/{id}/contacts` to be specific. You need to make a `DELETE` request, and pass a parameter `contact_ids` containing the comma-separated contact IDs you want to remove from the list.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/lists/remove-contacts-from-a-list

Answer (score 0):

```
// Update SendGrid contact's list association
$apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE';
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts';
$contactEmail = 'annahamilton@example.org';
$newListIds = ['057204d4-755b-4364-a0d1-ZZZZZ'];

$data = [
  'list_ids' => $newListIds,
  'contacts' => [['email' => $contactEmail]]
];
$payload = json_encode($data);
$headers = [
  'Authorization: Bearer ' . $apiKey,
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload)
];

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

[Understanding Contact Management in SendGrid](https://www.tempmail.us.com/en/sendgrid/modifying-sendgrid-contact-list-assignments-via-api)

Comment: what if next time I want to change the `list_ids` to another, is the `057204d4-755b-4364-a0d1-ZZZZZ` got removed?
it not getting removed thats the issue I'm facing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).